# Is there a way to determine if a cross-origin image would taint the canvas without painting it?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, cors

I'm writing a script that allows a user to enter an image URL.  I'd like to draw it to the canvas - but only if CORS policy allows me to do so without tainting the canvas.  Is there a straightforward way of determining whether the image would taint the canvas without first drawing it to a canvas?

Comment: To be clear, I won't know ahead of time what the `Access-control-allow-origin` header will return when accepting user input, nor what my `Origin` header in the request might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've been given the URL, you can simply force the HTMLImageElement's `crossOrigin` to be set to `"anonymous"`. If the image loads, it won't taint your canvas*, if its error event fired... you won't be able to draw it.

*Well, there is one case where this could still happen: if the image represents an other security threat for the browser, e.g svg images with `<foreignObject>` in Safari. For these edge cases, drawing on a 1x1 canvas is the only way to know.